# How to set a inner value for Input tag in HTML in IE

Tags: javascript, html, input, setattribute

I am trying to set dynamically innerHTML for value tag in IE.

The output I expect is this.

```
<input type="hidden" >a0FQ0000009rJfCMAU</input>
```

I tried innerHTML in IE but it was not working since it is supported for INPUT element. So, I tried the following out of desperation.

```
myElementId.setAttribute("value",textNodeId);
```

Unfortunately this is not what I want.

```
<input type="hidden" value="a0FQ0000009rJfCMAU">
```

Please advise.

Comment: Do `<input>` elements even support CDATA? [I think not](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4).

Comment: If the input is hidden, why does it need to be innerHTML and not value?

Comment: @pdknsk : Good question which i don't have an answer.. the piece of code i've given is a sample of an existing framework/library.

Comment: Why are you wanting to do this? The hidden type of input element does not support innerHTML, nor should it. a hidden element should always have it's value in the value field which you can access by using myElementId.value(textNodeId);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the `input` element's specification, you see that its **Content Model** should be empty. Thus, what you try to find is logically invalid HTML.

See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/the-input-element.html#the-input-element).

Comment: So that means it can set the value by using document.elementById().value?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change or set the value of input tag dynamically, you have to first define its name or id and then in javascript you can set it like

```
var txt = document.getElementById('yourtext');
txt.value = 'new value';
```

I hope this helps you.